# Reading a binary image directly to OpenCV Mat / numpy mat

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-requests, binary

Through some http requests I have been able to receive an image in binary form as
`b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\...`
and with:

```py
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(binary_content)
```

where `binary_content` is a string containing the data received through request I saved an image into a file.

Afterwards I can read this image with OpenCV methods. But I wanted to do a direct pass from binary string to OpenCV Mat without any in-betweens. `cv2.decode` method didn't work.

Comment: The image you received is not in binary format. It is in the hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 0):

`io.BytesIO` and `PIL` worked well. Closing this q.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay in the SciPy ecosystem, then the `imageio` library (previously part of SciPy) works well.

```
from imageio import imread

image_array = imread("image_path.jpg")
```

The code above gives you an uint8 array, if you want a float array, you can cast it easily

```
from imageio import imread

image_array = imread("image_path.jpg").astype(float)
```